# How can we get the reference of a public variable using the string name in another form in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have public variables in a module. I need to get the reference of the variable by using the String name of variable in another form. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I need something like the following code:

```
Dim Var1 As string
Dim sVariableName As String = "Var1"
GetReference(sVariableName).SetValue = "testing"
```

Comment: It sounds like there are serious problems with the design of your application if you need to do this. First of all, global variables are a bit of a code smell. But second, it's extremely rare that you should need to reference a variable by its string name. The name of a variable is a convenience for you, as the programmer. It's not typically used to reference the variable at run-time. Perhaps if you explained what you were trying to accomplish, rather than just your proposed solution, someone would be able to give you better advice.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, you might consider your design before going too far down this path. First off, if you are accessing what amounts to a public variable, you sould probably encapsulate it.

I also second what Cody Gray says - the variable name is primarily for the use and convenience of the programmer. If you are needing to pass a string to a method in order to grab a variable reference at run-time, this implies to me that some action of the user or client code is determining which variable to access (or something like that). This smells a bit; there is probably a better way to acheive the desired result.

Whatever it is you are trying to do, you are most likely better off defining a public function or property which returns a reference to the variable.

However, if you insist this needs to be done, your could proceed in either of the following ways:

A. In your Public Module, create a PRIVATE Dictionary(String, YourVariableType) (The variable aptions ARE of the same TYPE here, right?). Add the variable references to the Dictionary at application load, or whenever makes sense within your design. Then add a Public Function to the module which accepts a string as a parameter and returns a reference to the variable corresponding to the string name passed in. Use the .TryGetValue(ByVal VariableName, ByRef YourVariableType) method of the Dictionary to access the appropriate variable within the Dictionary.  NOTE: if the variables are value types, but you want to add REFERENCES to them within the Dictionary, you will need to add references to the Dictionary. I have never tried this, so I am not certain, but you may need to use a boxing operation of some sort to accomplish this. Or you might get away with simply passing by Ref.

B. Look into the use of reflection to access properties and public variables by string name. I have not tried THIS against a Public Module either, but it may work, look into it.

C. Re-read the other's posts about the use of public variables, and consider design alternatives.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In **WinForms**, pass a reference of the Main form to the other form (in it's constructor). Then you can have access to the public fields declared in the Main form.

Comment: That won't allow you to reference the variable by its string name.

Comment: True, but will allow changing the value of the variable which is what I think the OP wants - or not :)

Comment: Yeah, it's *half* of the solution, but not all of it. I just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: Like you, I have a hunch the OP doesn't really need the solution proposed in the question. (remains to be seen)